# Jenkins input step in case of Abort click

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, user-input

```
script {
        // Define Variable
         def USER_INPUT = input(
                message: 'User input required - Some Yes or No question?',
                parameters: [
                        [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                         choices: ['no','yes'],
                         name: 'input',
                         description: 'Menu - select box option']
                ])

        echo "The answer is: ${USER_INPUT}"
    }
```

Here When I click on Abort button I am getting 'null' value in ${USER_INPUT}

I don't understand why I am getting null. I am trying to add a textbox instead of dropdown but there also I am getting null when I click Abort button.

Comment: If you hit the abort button on the "input requested" view you should never see the echo statement printed to the build log at all.  You are aborting before the echo statement even runs.  Are you saying that the echo statement prints to your build log even if you hit the abort button?  Please update your question with the full build log

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli In my real project, I have added a textbox field using Class "text" of Input method instead of those choices(mentioned in my question). And I have to print that textbox field input value in email in case of Abort. For email I am using emailext plugin and email code I have mentioned inside abort{emailext code //input textbox field add for email body} . But when I am aborting I am getting null in my email body which is triggering as post action.

Comment: Ok well best of luck. In the future it would be beneficial if you post the actual code you're using.  You will get better responses on SO

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I have added my whole code here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811869/getting-null-as-value-from-input-step-method-in-case-of-abort-button-click-ins