# Getting 'null' as value from input step method in case of abort button click inside Jenkins pipeline for interactive input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, user-input, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {

        stage("Approval") {
            steps {
                script {

                    // Get the input in environment variable 'cmnt'
                    env.cmnt = input(
                            message: 'Do you want to approve the pipeline?',
                            parameters: [

                                    text(defaultValue: '',
                                            description: 'Enter your comment...',
                                            name: 'COMMENT')
                            ])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        success{
            emailext (
                subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' is approved.",
                body: """<p>APPROVER COMMENT:  '${env.cmnt}'</p>""",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
            )
        }
        aborted{
            emailext (
                subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' is aborted by approver",
                body: """<p>APPROVER COMMENT:  '${env.cmnt}'</p>""",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
            )
        }
    }

}
```

For success/Proceed button click, I am able to print comment inside email body whereas getting null as value in case of abort button click by approver at the time of approving the pipeline.

Comment: @Steve Miskiewicz Any answer of my question

Comment: @Chris Maggiulli Any answer of my question

Comment: @Steven any answer of my question

Comment: Is anyone please answer of my question. I am stuck with this abort pipeline in Jenkins... I am checking for the solution since one month